# Creating a show-more/show-less info box with + and - sign

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to create a box that has information in it that expands onclick of a '+' icon at the top right. The box should expand and include more information about that specific section and the '+' should transition into a '-' to allow the user to collapse the box to the original format that it was before.

The animation would be similar to  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_icon.asp

In simple terms: I need a "show-more/show-less" box that expands/collapses but with a '+' and '-' sign instead of 'show-more' or 'show-less'

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic knowledge of JS but here is the answer 
bit modified W3 codes

CSS

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2  {
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #333;  
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0px, -3px);
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0px, -3px);
}

.bar2 {  
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0px, -0px);
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0px, 0px);
  }

  .change .bar1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar2 {  
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0px, -0px);
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0px, 0px);
  }

.info{
display: none;
transition: 0.4s;

}
.change .info{
display: inherit;
transition: 0.4s;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>

  <div class="info">info</div>
</div>
```

JS(write inside the body tag)

```
<script>
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
</script>
```

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much.